# Wysihtml5 - Turn off HTML Sanitizer

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

I am building a page builder that is used like the WordPress page builder - it needs to not change any of the html that I program into the page (I am a programer and am using this - so that I can easily revision the page and it's changes while not having to deal with GIT's tools).

My reasoning in making this a wysiwyg editor is that I want to allow some of the non tech-savvy people I work with to edit some of the content (i.e. change images, fix spelling, add to the content...etc.).

I am using bootstrap-wysihtml5 ([link](http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/)).

### **Edit:**

After looking through the source code it turns out I want to turn off part of the HTML Sanitizer. Obviously I would like some help in making sure my code is good, but I don't want it to remove classes/tags/...etc.

Another question with the same jist: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681594/how-to-disabled-wysihtml5-html-clean-up-in-editor)

---

### Orrignal Question:

I have looked into how to do this, and have found that I can use the `ParserRules`. But after writing a good 25+ lines it seems to still be messing up my html.

Now I can continue and keep turning off these parserRules but I think this may not be the correct way to proceed as I will keep running into quirks of this genius system.

Is there a way to remove this so that it doesn't strip the html?

### Orrignal HTML

```
<form action="/contact-us/send" name="contact-form" id="contact-form" method="post">
    <table class="form-table"><tbody>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="fullname"><span class="req"></span> Full Name</label></td>
                <td class="form-input"><input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="email"><span class="req"></span> Email</label></td>
                <td class="form-input"><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="phone"><span class="req"></span> Phone</label></td>
                <td class="form-input"><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="form-label"><label for="feedback"><span class="req"></span> Questions/Feedback</label></td>
                <td class="form-input"><textarea name="feedback" id="feedback"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
</form>
```

### Current output HTML

```
<form>
    <span>
        <span>
            <label> Full Name</label>
            <input>
        </span>
        <span>
            <label> Email</label>
            <input>
        </span>
        <span>
            <label> Phone</label>
            <input>
        </span>
        <span>
            <label> Questions/Feedback</label>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </span>
    </span>
</form>
```

### Current ParserRules

```
        parserRules: {
            classes: {
                // (path_to_project/lib/css/wysiwyg-color.css)
                "wysiwyg-color-silver": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-gray": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-white": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-maroon": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-red": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-purple": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-fuchsia": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-green": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-lime": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-olive": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-yellow": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-navy": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-blue": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-teal": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-aqua": 1,
                "wysiwyg-color-orange": 1
            },
            tags: {
                "b": {},
                "i": {},
                "br": {},
                "ol": {},
                "ul": {},
                "li": {},
                "h1": {},
                "h2": {},
                "h3": {},
                "blockquote": {},
                "u": 1,
                "img": {
                    "check_attributes": {
                        "width": "numbers",
                        "alt": "alt",
                        "src": "url",
                        "height": "numbers"
                    }
                },
                "a": {
                    set_attributes: {
                        target: "_blank",
                        rel: "nofollow"
                    },
                    check_attributes: {
                        href: "url" // important to avoid XSS
                    }
                },
                "span": 1,
                "div": 1,
                // to allow save and edit files with code tag hacks
                "code": 1,
                "pre": 1,
                "label": {},
                "legend": {},
                "textarea": {},
                "html": {},
                "button": {},
                "select": {},
                "option": {},
                "iframe": {},
                "form": {},
                "head": {},
                "object": {},
                "noscript": {},
                "svg": {},
                "input": {},
                "meta": {},
                "video": {},
                "canvas": {},
                "source": {},
                "frame": {},
                "style": {},
                "xml": {},
                "param": {},
                "audio": {},
                "link": {},
                "script": {},
                "colgroup": {},
                "comment": {},
                "header": {}
            }
        },
```

I am also trying to toggle how it is removing classes (as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906030/how-to-toggle-remove-classes-in-wysihtml5) question asks - no idea what he's doing... but the title fits) - this seems to be controlled by `ParserRules:classes`; again, I think I need to turn off the whole ParserRules.

Comment: Why don't you write the HTML yourself ? It's more code to write the table == more work == more hours spent building something...

Comment: Because I want to make it so that some of the non-technical savvy people can edit small parts of the content (i.e. change images, spelling...etc.) The system also makes it a lot easier to load dynamic content in the pages do tricks of combining content, and makes parsing it without `eval` much easier.

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681594/how-to-disabled-wysihtml5-html-clean-up-in-editor/17656572#17656572